# beforeCreate method is not being called upon creating new user

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am using `sailsjs version 0.11.0`. I want when new user is created then their password must be encrypted before storing it into the database. For this, I am using `bcrypt` library. I added a method `beforeCreate` in `User.js` model like following

```
beforeCreate: function (values, next) {
      if (!values.password || values.password != values.confimation) {
          return next({ err: ["Password doesnt match password confirmation."] });
      }
      console.log(values);
      require('bcrypt').hash(values.password, 10, function passwordEncrypted (err, encryptedPassword) {
          if (err) return next(err);
          values.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
          // values.online = true;
          next();
      });
  }
```

The problem is when I create a new user `beforeCreate` method is never called whereas it should get called upon `create` action.

**Where am I making mistake and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common mistake I see people is that they put the call back (in this case beforeCreate) on the attributes object.

I would check to make sure it is on the module exports object in your user.js file

The second thing you need to check is if you have a validation error. If you have a validation error then it will also not run. I can only assume this is not the case as your question would probably be different if the user was not being created.

Comment: True. I had the beforeCreate on the attribute object. It should exist outside it, like a sibling to the attribute object within module.exports